# How to Allow Characters in Certain Spot in String

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to parse a date. The problem, is my regular expression omits any letter because I want to avoid `01-28-2019 UTC` or any letters outside of the main date. Now, it works fine when the date is formatted like I just listed, however it fails when we get a date formatted like `28-JAN-19`.

```
var sourceValue = Regex.Replace("28-JAN-19", @"[A-Za-z]", "");
var parsed = DateTime.Parse(sourceValue);
```

The date I need to parse can be in a few different formats. Can a regular expression be used to handle this? If so, what tweaks are needed to trim any letters outside of the `xx-xx-xx` part of the string?

`28-JAN-19`
`28-01-19`
`28-JAN-19 13:15:00`
`28-01-19 13:15:00`
`28-01-2019 13:15:00`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to parse the correct date out of a string like `foo bar 29-JAN-19 blah blubb` or `foo bar 28-01-19 13:15:00 blah blubb`?

Comment: You can OR (use pipe) expressions so you can have different options.

Comment: @derpirscher That's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This RegEx should match all the examples you provided:

```
[0-9]{2}-([A-Za-z]{3}|[0-9]{2})-[0-9]{2,4}( [0-9][0-9]?:[0-9][0-9]?:[0-9][0-9])?
```

It does make a couple of assumptions though, based on your examples. First, it assumes all your dates will always start with a 2-digit day. It also assumes that your month abbreviations will be 3 letters long. It also assumes that your hours, minutes and seconds will all be 2 digits long. Let me know if any of these assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, those are valid assumptions, the problem is that there could be endless formats. I'm starting to think RegEx isn't my best option for this. So, if I go this route, basically I need to pipe together a bunch of potential formats, right?

Comment: @James - Well there could be hundreds of formats. Depending on what you are making, your best bet might be to ask the user to supply it in a standard format. e.g. `Please enter the date (DD-MM-YYYY) -->`. Something like that. In which case, @stimms would have the better answer.

Comment: Valid. It's not a UI input, so setting the format isn't going to work. We're getting data from a handful of sources so the date formats vary.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are likely not your best bet. If you know the full set of formats you might encounter then you can use the regular DateTime.ParseExact with a format string. Check for a `FormatException` to know if you've successfully parsed the date. If your months are using English abbreviations then be sure to pass in an English culture

```
DateTime.ParseExact("28-JAN-19", "dd-MMM-yy", new CultureInfo("en"));
```